# Data isn't a known property

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I've looked at other answers and I think I'm doing it right? But still I get this error!

My component looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./autocomplete.component.css']
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() datatype: number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The html where I'm calling it looks like this:

```
<autocomplete [datatype]="2"></autocomplete>
```

I have used Angular CLI to generate everything so it is all in the module and everything...

Comment: Your selector is `app-autocomplete`. So you must not use `<autocomplete>`, but `<app-autocomplete>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pretty obvious, you used the wrong selector (missing a dash). The selector property in your metadata should match your HTML tag `app-autocomplete`

Comment: @Firenter You are welcome! We all do this kind of mistakes from time to time :)